# ASP.NET Core API - How to get Mandate Record based on Login loggedInUserId

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I have this code:

```
    public MandateGetDto FromMandateToMandateGetDto(Mandate mandate)
    {
        MandateGetDto mandateDto = new MandateGetDto();
          var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
          var loggedInUserId = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        mandateDto.MerchantId = mandate.MerchantId;
        mandateDto.DueDate = mandate.DueDate;
        mandateDto.StartDate = mandate.StartDate;
        mandateDto.EndDate = mandate.EndDate;
        return mandateDto;
    }
```

What I have above selects all the records.

I am using:

> var loggedInUserId = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

to get the logged in user Id:

But how do I select the records in Mandate where **MerchantId = loggedInUserId** ?

Thanks

Comment: A new, empty `ClaimsPrincipal` instance won't contain any claims. Your `loggedInUserId` will be blank.

Comment: @RichardDeeming - What do I do to get this data based on loggedInUserId?

Comment: You need to access the logged-in user somehow. Either pass it to your method, or inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` class to get the current `HttpContext` and retrieve its `User` property.